# Why am I not able to plot separate bar chart for each product (in dataset) in the same chart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, exploratory-data-analysis

My dataset is something like this.

[image: Image of dataset]

I want to Read face cream and face wash product sales data and show it using the bar chart
and the bar chart should display the number of units sold per month for each product and Add a separate bar for each product in the same chart.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x=df['facecream'], y=df['total_units'], height=0.5)
ax.bar(x=df['facewash'], z=df['total_units'], height=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

the complete error message also contains this line:

"*TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars*"

that means x and y arguments should be size-1 arrays and that is the reason you get this error.

**Solution:**

```
for x,y in zip(df['facecream'],df['total_units']):
    ax.bar(x=x, y=y, height=0.5)
```

(you can do the same with df['facewash'])

so we iterate over them and plot them one by one

Comment: This is also throwing error :   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: There was a little mistake sorry. checkout the edited one